# How to set Mapping in Mapstruct to get the Parent's field in Child's DTO?

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

```java
public class Parent {
    String parentField;
}

public class Child extends Parent{

}

public class ChildDTO{
    String parentField;
}

@Mapper (componentModel="spring")
public interface ChildMapper {
    ChildDTO toDTO(Child child);
}
```

How set Mapping in Mapstruct to get the Parent's field in Child's DTO

I have tried this:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ChildMapper {

   @Mapping(source = "parentField", target = "parentField")
   ChildDTO toDTO(Child child);

}
```

also I tried

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ChildMapper {
   
    @Mapping(source = "parentField", target = "parentField", qualifiedByName = "mapParentField")
    ChildDTO toDTO(Child child);

    @Named("mapParentField")
    default String mapParentField(Parent parent) {
        return parent.getParentField();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Getters and Setters.
For simplicity I'm using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/#)

Parent:

```
@Data
public class Parent {

     private String parentField;
     
}
```

Child:

```
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Child extends Parent {

}
```

ChildDTO:

```
@Data
public class ChildDTO {

    private  String parentField;
     
}
```

ChildMapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING)
public interface ChildMapper {
   
    ChildMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ChildMapper.class);
    
    ChildDTO toDTO(Child child);
    
}
```

Generated ChildMapperImpl:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-10-04T22:29:28+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 1.4.300.v20221108-0856, environment: Java 17.0.5 (Eclipse Adoptium)"
)
@Component
public class ChildMapperImpl implements ChildMapper {

    @Override
    public ChildDTO toDTO(Child child) {
        if ( child == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ChildDTO childDTO = new ChildDTO();

        childDTO.setParentField( child.getParentField() );

        return childDTO;
    }
}
```

As you can see the generated mapper is mapping correctly the field from parent to childDTO.

There is no need to add @Mapping since they both have same field name.

It is perfectly working also in the opposite direction, so if I add  toEntity method into the ChildMapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING)
public interface ChildMapper {
   
    ChildMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ChildMapper.class);
    
    ChildDTO toDTO(Child child);
    
    Child toEntity(ChildDTO dto);
    
}
```

the ChildMapperImpl will look like that:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-10-04T22:36:40+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 1.4.300.v20221108-0856, environment: Java 17.0.5 (Eclipse Adoptium)"
)
@Component
public class ChildMapperImpl implements ChildMapper {

    @Override
    public ChildDTO toDTO(Child child) {
        if ( child == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ChildDTO childDTO = new ChildDTO();

        childDTO.setParentField( child.getParentField() );

        return childDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public Child toEntity(ChildDTO dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Child child = new Child();

        child.setParentField( dto.getParentField() );

        return child;
    }
}
```

When classes (Parent, Child, ChildDTO) are annotated with only @Getter and @SuperBuilder, the ChildMapperImpl looks like this:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2023-10-06T20:23:22+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 1.4.300.v20221108-0856, environment: Java 17.0.5 (Eclipse Adoptium)"
)
@Component
public class ChildMapperImpl implements ChildMapper {

    @Override
    public ChildDTO toDTO(Child child) {
        if ( child == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ChildDTO.ChildDTOBuilder<?, ?> childDTO = ChildDTO.builder();

        childDTO.parentField( child.getParentField() );

        return childDTO.build();
    }

    @Override
    public Child toEntity(ChildDTO dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Child.ChildBuilder<?, ?> child = Child.builder();

        child.parentField( dto.getParentField() );

        return child.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul Marcelin Bejan, I had **@Builder** under Child class, when I delete **@Builder**, then it starts working. And I wonder how I can solve the problem without deleting the **@Builder**?

Comment: because Builder doesn't know the fields from superclass, you need to use @SuperBuilder projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder

Comment: could you provide an example, please?

Comment: See the last part of the answer!