# Properties from the super class are not mapped. MapStruct to map field in base class

Tags: java, mapstruct

Unknown property "parentField" in **target**. I can't set parentField to Child class, however there are setters and getters

```
public class Parent {
    String parentField;
}

public class Child extends Parent{
}

public class ChildDTO{
String parentField;
}

@Mapper (componentModel="spring")
public interface ChildMapper {
   @Mapping(target="parentField", source="parentField")
    Child toEntity(ChildDto dto);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Mapping in Mapstruct to get the Parent's field in Child's DTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77230604/how-to-set-mapping-in-mapstruct-to-get-the-parents-field-in-childs-dto)

Comment: Thank you, Paul Marcelin Bejan, I had **@Builder** under Child class, when I delete **@Builder**, then it starts working. And I wonder how I can solve the problem without deleting the **@Builder**?

Comment: Are you using Lombok? Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/47684351/1115491?